# given a prefix boolean expression, construct its truth table (with C )

Tags: c, prefix

The given expression has most 26 variables 'A','B',.....,'Z',

and 3 operators,'&','|','^'(XOR).

For example: input
4 7 &|AB|CA

4 means the number of variable(A,B,C,D)

7 means the length of prefix expression.

output:

A B C D OUTPUT

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0

0 0 1 0 0

.

.

Now I have a algorithm to evaluate prefix expression:

```
int Expr(){
    char c = getchar();
    if c is an operator
        op1 = Expr()
        op2 = Expr()
        return op1 c op2
    else if c is a variable
        return the value of c
}
```

My question is how could I make the variable A,B,C,D... become 0 or 1,

and execute n^2 times to build the truth table.

I try to set an array[26]={'A',...,'Z'} to match the input,

but it didn't work.

Comment: `unsigned long a = 0; for (i = 'A' to 'Z') {val[i] = bool(a); a >>=1} a++;`

Comment: @ibug seems a waste to have the array be 91 elements big when it only really needs to be 26

Comment: Has the for ( to ) loop been recently added to C ?

Comment: Treat it as pseudo-code please.

Comment: It is executed 26 times on the value a = 0, and then a is incremented to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could. A simple solution relies on the "n-bit vector" represented by a number `v` between 0 and 2^n-1.

You enumerate them with the loop

```
for (int v = 0; v < (1<<n); v++) {
    ...
}
```

Then use the rightmost bit for A. It is set iff `v & 1` is not 0.

B is set if `(v >> 1) & 1` is not zero. C is `(v >> 2) & 1`, etc.

Actually, for any `char letter`; it is  `(v >> (letter-'A')) & 1`.

Comment: I don't get it though, but I will think about more.
Thanks! !